# How do I get the file URI from an EntityMetadataWrapper object?

Tags: 7, entities

Getting hold of file objects related to nodes through a field is easy using an `EntityMetadataWrapper`:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$images = $wrapper->field_images;
```

So that's great. However, I want to use some of the properties of the standard file object, and they're not available. When I look at the properties available on `$images[0]->file` using the above code, I see these:

- fid
- name
- mime
- size
- url
- timestamp
- owner

Most notably, `uri` is missing, and in its place there's a `url` property, which is the full external URL to the image file. I want to manipulate these images via their URI (create thumbs, etc), so I'm left doing this:

```
$fid = $images[0]->file->fid->value();
$uri = file_load($fid)->uri;
```

Which seems to negate the whole point of using an `EntityMetadataWrapper` in the first place.

What am I missing? Where is the URI on the wrapped file object? If it's not available, for the love of all things good and pure, why not?!

I'm aware I could deconstruct the URL back to a URI, but that also feels very unnecessary.

Comment: Are you using file_entity?

Comment: @MPD Ahhhh, great call, no I'm not...maybe I shouldn't be expecting to see what I'd consider 'properties' if the object isn't acting like an entity. URL seems a strange choice instead of URI for the Entity module guys to have chosen, though. If the answer is "you're going to need to implement `hook_entity_property_info_alter()`" then that's fine, just wanted to know

Comment: I'm actually not sure if that will make a difference, but having that module enabled does end up in some subtle differences here and there.  I have found File integration with EMW a bit lacking in other places, but haven't been bothered enough by it to submit a patch.

Comment: @MPD I think it will - just found out the 'offender' is `entity_metadata_system_entity_property_info()`, where a bunch of new properties get tacked onto `$info['file']['properties']`. I'm willing to bet if file_entity was in there that array would already have the entity properties themselves in there. I'll try to write an answer up later or tomorrow if no-one's already done it

Comment: Did a quick test and `uri` is there with file_entity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big thanks to MPD for pointing me in the right direction. In short, without the [File Entity module](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity), files aren't entities, so they don't naturally have the 'properties' I was expecting.

The Entity module provides some on their behalf, but URI isn't one of them. Fortunately it's very simple to make it available using [`hook_entity_property_info_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7) and a custom property callback:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['file']['properties']['uri'] = array(
    'label' => t("URI"),
    'description' => t("The URI of the file."),
    'getter callback' => 'MYMODULE_entity_get_file_properties',
    'schema field' => 'uri',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_entity_get_file_properties($file, array $options, $name) {
  switch ($name) {
    case 'uri':
      return $file->uri;
      break;
  }
}
```

After that, `$images[0]->file->uri->value()` is available as expected.

Answer (score 8):

Below works without the hack:

```
 $node_wrapper->field_media[0]->value()['uri'];
```

Comment: It's good to point out that this is supported from PHP 5.4 on.

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me to get the full path of a single image...

```
// wrap it
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', node_load(16));
// get the value
$image = $wrapper->field_image->value();
// check it
if ($image) {
   // get the full path
   $path = file_create_url($image['uri']);
}
print_r($path);
```

Alternatively...

```
  $image = $wrapper->field_image->value();
  $image_path = $image ? file_create_url($image['uri']) : '';
```